# How to get Child Class Name Instead of Base?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I have a base class and using nlog logging. In my base class I have a method that gets passed in a logger object and then logs it to that logger.

When it logs it, logs it as the base class, I was hoping it would use the child class name.

```
<logger name="Uploads" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="Uploads" />


public void Child : Parent
{
    private readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Uploads")

    public void ParentMethod(Logger logger)
    {
            logger.Info("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your parameter `logger` is going to hide the field `logger`. Was that intentional? If it was, the logger name you get depends on what you pass into the method.

Comment: I would recommend never passing `Loggers` as parameters. A static variabele for each class is recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `${callsite}` in the `layout` to determine the format of log message.

```
layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${callsite:includeNamespace=false:className=true:fileName=false:includeSourcePath=false:methodName=false}|${message}"
```

This will log messages in following format:

```
2018-03-15 18:11:43.1173|TRACE|{className}|{message}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is the NLog team [considers this a breaking change](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2579) so it hasn't been resolved yet.  However, there are a couple workarounds that might work.

### Workaround 1

Name the logger explicitly for each child class using [GetType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype) and the `Name` property and pass it to [GetLogger](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.0.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_GetLogger_1.htm):

```cs
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().Name);
```

### Workaround 2

Create a custom [sub-class logger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-create-Logger-for-sub-classes).

### Workaround 3

Add to the base class custom logging methods that automatically add the child class name using [GetType().Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype) along with the message.  Below is some example pseudocode:

```cs
public class BaseClass
{
    protected Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("BaseClass");
  
    protected void LogError(string message)
    {
        logger.Error($"{GetType().Name}: {message}");
    }

    protected void LogInfo(string message)
    {
        logger.Info($"{GetType().Name}: {message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: The "short answer" is that the suggested solution is not possible, because `ReflectedType` is not available on StackTraces. But you are ofcourse wellcome to create a pull-request for the NLog-project to prove that I'm wrong. And yes the [NLog Wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-create-Logger-for-sub-classes) describes how to handle the situation (Your workAround 1 + 2 that are pretty much the same)